# Monitor Resolution Changes after Login (Lower than Optimal)

Tags: 11.10, resolution, monitor, screen

Problem: Boot and LoginScreen resolution are O.K. - 1366x768, but after login the resolution drop down to 1024x768. In the options I can select the 1366x768 resolution again, but looks like it doesn't save it, because in the next reboot it drop back again to 1024x768.

I have a Intel Integrated Video Card, on Dell Inspiron 1545 running Ubuntu 11.10, 4GB RAM & 320 HD.

Comment: WORKAROUND: 
I used this comand `xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1366x768` and linked it to this keyboard shortcut: **Crtl+Alt+z**, and I run it after login, and that is.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running this command at log in or through your short cut you may want to take a look at you **monitors.xml** file.

1. Open up a terminal (ctrl+alt+t)
2. Go to your config folder (cd ~/.config)
3. Open up your file for editing (gedit monitors.xml)
4. Your resolution will be listed here as `<width>` and `<height>`
5. Change them to `<width>1366</width>` and `768

You can find a more detailed description here... [Ubuntu 11.10 dual monitor set up instructions](http://www.sudo-juice.com/ubuntu-11-10-dual-monitors-set-up-not-saving/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use update-rc.d for start-only or stop-only scripts

Start my script on startup :

```
# update-rc.d -f my_script start 99 2 3 4 5 .
```

where

```
- start is the argument given to the script (start, stop).
- 99 is the start order of the script (1 = first one, 99= last one)
- 2 3 4 5 are the runlevels to start
```

**Dont forget the dot at the end**
More info in /etc/rcS.d/README

Start my_script on shutdown and reboot :

```
# update-rc.d -f my_script start 90 0 6 .
```

Stop my_script on halt and reboot :

```
# update-rc.d -f my_script reboot 90 0 6 .
```

**Note**: your script will be `xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1366x768`