# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS never remember primary screen/monitor resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution, nvidia-settings, gnome-control-center

I use Ubuntu GNOME with Nvidia graphic card (two HDMI and one DVI output).
My monitor is connected through VGA - DVI adapter and work natively in `1920x1080`.

- Since I was unable to change my screen resolution, I spent enormous amount of time to play with `xrandr` command as well as trying different graphic drivers.
- I've tried to provide resolution in `monitors.xml` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83538/monitor-resolution-changes-after-login-lower-than-optimal), but it seems that it doesn't help.

Finally, I get it - since Ubuntu didn't recognize my monitor, the only I needed was to edit

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and set Horizontal and Vertical refreshing rate.

After restart, I was able to finally change my monitor resolution in both - `gnome-control-center` as well as 'NVIDIA X Server Settings'. There was no error, so I thought that settings are saved properly.

However, after rebooting my system... I saw resolution `1024x768`. I've tried to reinstall `gnome-control-center`, but it doesn't help - each time when I reboot, I need to manually go to 'Displays' and set resolution back.

- I've tried to add [xrandr commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6137/saving-monitor-settings) to startup programs, but it seems that my screen misbehaves - I see black background.
- This idea (to use xrandr as startup process) is also mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361884/monitor-resolution-cant-be-saved), but it seems that it works only after booting Gnome - otherwise screen is stretched or misbehaves.

Is there any solution to save mentioned settings 'by hard' (is it a bug in Gnome?).

Comment: I've tried to add    xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --rate 60 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 1920x1080    to /etc/init.d/rc.local, /etc/rc.local, ~/.xprofile, /etc/gdm/Init/Default and create my custom scripts. Nothing helps.

Comment: I checked - there's no such problems in KDE and MATE (lightdm and kdm) - screen resolution is constantly equal to 1920x1080 (seems that mentioned above script with xrandr works). Is it a bug in Gnome?